# Alert says "iTunes can not be opened while it is being updated." but nothing ever changes

Tags: itunes, macos, imac, software-update

For the past week I have been getting this message when I try to open iTunes.

[image: iTunes is being updated]

It doesn't matter how long I wait, nothing ever changes. If I reboot my computer and try to open iTunes immediately after startup, iTunes will open normally. But eventually this same message will appear again after closing iTunes and trying to open it again later. I am running El Capitan 10.11.6 on a late 2012 iMac. Has anyone else experienced this or a similar issue and does anyone know of way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a screen capture of activity monitor?

Comment: There's a lot of stuff going on in activity monitor. Much more than would fit in one screen shot. Is there a specific process or section of activity monitor you want to see?

Comment: itunes and some process look like itunes.. or update..

Comment: iTunes doesn't show up in activity monitor

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58096678/1084174

Answer (score 1):

This thread talks about checking for OS updates, and also trying to start the computer in safe mode:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7416168?start=0&tstart=0

If you don't have any OS updates to do, you might as well just download a new iTunes app and install a fresh copy:
https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/

Comment: I've read this before. I made a 2nd test user account, logged in with that account and iTunes started up just fine. So I logged out of it and back into my normal account and again iTunes started up just fine. I don't know why but for some reason that seems to have made the issue go away. I didn't delete the test account afterwards so it's unknown to me whether or not doing so would have any effect on the issue.

Comment: @I0_ol, That is a new one. LOL. You should post that as the answer and accept that. I haven't see that provided as an option.

Comment: Hahaha it's actually mentioned in the first link you posted. I just didn't delete the account after testing. It does seem to have resolved the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I logged into another user account and ran iTunes which started up just fine. So I logged out of it and back into my normal account and again iTunes started up just fine again.